Midbar Kodesh, reason for title
The sefer Midbar Kodesh contains the teachings of Rav Shalom Rokeach, the first rebbe of Belz. The title Midbar Kodesh appears to be an intentional mispronunciation of "Midbar Kadesh." Why is this the title chosen for this sefer, who chose this title, and what is its intended meaning?
